# Like functionality in react-native

Tags: react-native

This is regarding React Native Mobile App Development.

I am facing an issue with "Like" functionality for a List-view Items.

When i like a List-view Items, it works fine and the colour changes to blue instantly. But on existing the app & opening it again, the like count is increased but the colour set to the default again.

Please help me with this issue!

Comment: any code snippet will be helpful!

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: You might need to preserve the state to some `store` otherwise it will get reset, when the particular component is `unmounted`.